# Calling async componets inside a component in Vuejs though axios call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am building a small application on `VueJS` where I am having a api which gives information about the components to be loaded while rendering the page.

I have setup `vue-router` as:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

export const router = new VueRouter({
    routes:
        [
            {
                path: '/',
                component: Vue.component('welcome', () => import('../Components/Admin/Login.vue')),
                name: 'login'
            },
            {
                path: '/:page',
                component: Vue.component('dashboard', () => import('../Components/Admin/Dashboard/Dashboard.vue')),
                name: 'dashboard'
            },

        ]
});
```

Now this `dashboard` component asynchronously calls the component to be loaded, something like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar has-shadow">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-brand">
                        <a class="nav-item is-centered">
                            <img src="nits-assets/images/logo.png" alt="NitsEditor Logo" width="170" height="50">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-menu">
                        <div class="navbar-end is-centered">
                            <div class="navbar-item">
                                <p class="control"><a class="button is-primary is-outlined is-rounded">Log out</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div class="section" id="dashboard">
            <div class="columns">
                <aside class="column is-2 menu-section">
                    <nav class="menu is-centered">
                        // Menu section
                    </nav>
                </aside>

                <main class="column" id="main-section">
                    <page-title :title="title"></page-title>

                    <div class="columns is-multiline">
                        <div class="column">
                            <top-seller-widget></top-seller-widget>
                        </div>

                </main>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "dashboard",
        data() {
            return {
                pageComponents: '',
                title: '',
                description: ''
            }
        },
        components: {
            'PageTitle': () => import('./PageTitle'),
            'TopSellerWidget': () => import('./TopSellerWidget')
        },
        created() {
            axios.get('/api/page-components?slug='+this.$route.params.page).then(response => {
                if(response.status === 200)
                {
                    this.title = response.data.page.title
                    console.log(response.data)
                }
            })
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    // Some styling
</style>
```

As you can see I am trying to import components in component section asynchronously:

```
components: {
    'PageTitle': () => import('./PageTitle'),
    'TopSellerWidget': () => import('./TopSellerWidget')
},
```

And calling the components inside the template:

```
<div class="section" id="dashboard">
    <div class="columns">
        <aside class="column is-2 menu-section">
            <nav class="menu is-centered">
                // Menu section
            </nav>
        </aside>

        <main class="column" id="main-section">
            <page-title :title="title"></page-title>

            <div class="columns is-multiline">
                <div class="column">
                    <top-seller-widget></top-seller-widget>
                </div>

        </main>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now while getting the axios call data:

I get in this format:

```
{
    components: [
        {name: 'PageTitle', location:'./PageTitle', 'data': {title: 'Dashboard'}},
        {name: 'TopSellerWidget', location:'./TopSellerWidget', 'data': NULL}
    ]
}
```

Then I checked whether I can load my components when we get a response:

```
axios.get('/api/page-components?slug='+this.$route.params.page).then(response => {
    if(response.status === 200)
    {
        this.title = response.data.page.title
        if(response.data.page.content)
        {
            Vue.component('PageTitle', () => import('./PageTitle'))
            Vue.component('TopSellerWidget', () => import('./TopSellerWidget'))

        }
        console.log(response.data)
    }
})
```

It worked fine, but when I'm trying to make it dynamic:

```
axios.get('/api/page-components?slug='+this.$route.params.page).then(response => {
    if(response.status === 200)
    {
        this.title = response.data.page.title
        if(response.data.page.content)
        {
            response.data.page.content.components.forEach(function (val, index) {
                Vue.component(val.name, () => import(val.location))
            })

        }
        console.log(response.data)
    }
})
```

I am getting errors:

[image: Compilation error]

And in console I get:

[image: Console logs]

What can I do in such condition?

Comment: The first thing I would do is fix the missing comma.

Comment: Could you put a log inside the for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you almost got the answer yourself. The error log probably says that `import(val.location)` is importing an dependency but the dependency is an expression. So you should replace it with a name instead, like you did in your experiment.

Also, I am not sure if it is necessary to asynchronously import the two components (`PageTitle` and `TopSellerWidget`) inside `Dashboard`. `Dashboard` itself is already loaded asynchronously, so any of its dependencies, such as `PageTitle` is also loaded only when you request `Dashboard`. And since you need both `PageTitle` and `TopSellerWidget` to properly render your `Dashboard`, you may as well get them along with `Dashboard`, rather than spending one more round trip on the wire.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, but suppose I have a huge set of components where I am having different `PageTitle` and `TopSellerWidget` in respective of their styles/layouts, I don't want to load all the components and make a big bundled file, In-fact want them to load whenever it is necessary or with respect to end user accessibility. Can I make a js file for importing all the components asynchronously, and import them to `main.js` file so that it won't effect the size of bundle?

Comment: If you dashboard may (possibly) need a lot of component but in fact only use a few of them, it makes sense to load the components async. In this case, your first attempt (define the `components: { ... }` inside `Dashboard` component definition is probably more suitable. Vue will only load those that are actually used, not all of them. This way you saves the headache of deciding when and what to load. It is also easier to read, as people from the official guide will tend to expect them in `components: { ... }`